# Using Angular 8, Trying to display image in the template file which is received through an external API call

Tags: typescript, image, api, angular8, src

I am using Angular 8 for my development. I have a scenario where I need to display some image in the template and the image content is coming from an external API call. The response of the Base64 from the API is taking time so that i am able to display the image in the template. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the image that is received from API as a background image. First, insert the DomSanitizer in your component

```
constructor(private dom: DomSanitizer)
```

and in the HTML where you want to set as background add

```
[style.background-image]="trustImage('url(' + value + ')')"
```

Now you need to make the image trusted using the trustImage function

```
trustImage(item) {
    return this.dom.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(item);
}
```

Once the image is trusted it will get displayed.For more information, refer https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer